# Phonegap and Meteor, using Phonegap Build Service

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-build

I am attempting to develop a **Phonegap application** using **Meteor**, but I am having trouble figuring out how to structure the application folders correctly.

Here are the steps that I have followed so far:

1. On a Windows 7 machine, I downloaded Phonegap and following instructions therein, created a Windows Phone 7 project in Visual Studio. I was able to write some sample code using Phonegap library and tested it successfully in the Windows Phone 7 emulator.
2. Installed meteor, created an example project. And now I am trying to merge the sample meteor code into the www folder in my Phonegap project, and I need help to figure out how to structure the app inside the www folder i.e. which scripts go in the server and client folders.

Also, what would be the steps to submit this meteor app to Phonegap Build service and what gets deployed to the Meteor server?

I am guessing the Server folder should not be part of the www folder that is uploaded to PhoneGap Build?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/guaka/meteor-phonegap, you can use the same www folder it makes for your WP app

Comment: I found that it is not that easy to do. But what you can do is do a redirect in your index.html. window.location = "you url" You can still use the phonegap plugins. The secret is to use the appCache plugin (new in meteor this month) to store all the templates and js in the phone. And will update when changed on server side.

Answer (score 2):

For iPhone and iPad PhoneGap installations, you don't even need to put add any files into the www folder.  All you need to do is adjust the CDViewController.m file, and set the self.wwwFolderName variable to your published Meteor app url, like so (line 170, approximately):

```
self.wwwFolderName = @"http://myapp.meteor.com";
```

You may want to try similar approaches, and keep the PhoneGap build ultra-light to begin.  Test the Phonegap Build Service by using PhoneGap as simply a wrapper to the Meteor App.  Once you confirm the PhoneGap Build, then add in the local appcache package, and other features.